# What does page speed class as a small file size?

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed, gtmetrix

I'm running a test on a page in GTMetrix.
I get a warning, Inline small javascript.

What determines the small file size, is there a threshold or minmum amount a characters or bytes?

Comment: i know nothing official, but a packet is usually <4kb, so that's probably a good place to start.

Comment: I've noticed that error for anything under 5 lines of code in an external file. Can you post a  link to your site? I can probably make some suggestions for you.